# db contains records with empty username and suspicous db entries

Tags: mysql, security, permissions, mariadb, sql-grant

I want to make sure that my php website and the user to login the database has only mandatory permissions / privileges on the maria db. 
Also i would like to know

- if certain records are suspicious or at least an insecure configuration
- how to safely delete certain records if it is advisable to do so

The records are

1. from `mysql.user` the record `User=webphp AND Host=%`
2. from `information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES` the record `GRANTEE='webphp'@'%'`
3. from `mysql.db` the record `User="" and host='%'`

### Records inside my database

mysql.user

```
SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user where Host in ('%', '127.0.0.1', '::1', 'localhost');

+-----------+--------+
| Host      | User   |
+-----------+--------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root   |
| ::1       | root   |
| localhost | root   |
| %         | webphp |  <-- Can i delete this to avoid connections from outside?
| localhost | webphp |
+-----------+--------+
```

information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES where PRIVILEGE_TYPE = 'USAGE';

+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
| GRANTEE              | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE |
+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 'webphp'@'localhost' | def           | USAGE          |
| 'webphp'@'%'         | def           | USAGE          | <-- Can i delete this?
+----------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

mysql.db

```
SELECT Host, User, Length(User), Db FROM mysql.db;

+-----------+--------+--------------+---------+
| Host      | User   | Length(User) | Db      |
+-----------+--------+--------------+---------+
| %         |        |            0 | test    |  <-- AFAIK i have no Db named test
| %         |        |            0 | test\_% |  <-- same here - Delete?
| localhost | webphp |            6 | webphp  |
+-----------+--------+--------------+---------+
```

From the [MariaDB Server Documentation about mysql.db](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldb-table/) it is unclear to me if records in `mysql.db` should have an empty string "" in the column `User`. The docs [information-schema-innodb_sys_datafiles-table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-innodb_sys_datafiles-table/) do not state if i can delete records here.

#### Questions regarding granting only mandatory rights / privileges

I plan to grant these rights

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES  
ON *webphp.* TO 'webphp'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mySuperSecretPW';
```

The above should ensure that `user webphp` can only connect to the `db webphp` if he connects from the same hardware

1. Are these rights sufficient? Did i miss any?
2. Is it a good idea?

#### Questions for `db=test and user =""`

1. Should i remove the records inside `mysql.db` where the field / column `User` is empty?
2. To my knowledge i have no Db named `test` or `test\_%`. Can i delete these records?

#### Questions for `db=webphp and user ="webphp"`

1. `information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES` to my understanding `GRANTEE = 'webphp'@'%'`  allows the user webphp to connect from anywhere. If my database is running on the same hardware can and should i remove it?
2. `mysql.user` can i delete the record `host=% and user=webphp` to avoid use from other servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES  
ON *webphp.* TO 'webphp'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mySuperSecretPW';
```

*Are these rights sufficient? Did i miss any?*

Be more specific on the database name and use `webphp.*`. Do not give the user `delete` or `alter` authority if it really doesn't need it. If your application needs to delete things have a column in the table that flags something to be deleted.

*Is it a good idea?*

Yes.

*Questions for db=test and user =""*

Delete users and databases that aren't needed.

*information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES to my understanding GRANTEE = 'webphp'@'%' allows the user webphp to connect from anywhere. If my database is running on the same hardware can and should i remove it?*

Yes

*mysql.user can i delete the record host=% and user=webphp to avoid use from other servers?*

Yes

Comment: If i delete ´'webphp'@'%' ´ do i have to be aware of anything? For instance that localhost ip must be 127.0.0.1. Do i have to add `::1`  as an IPv6 loopback address and also add an entry that uses `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: For a general user, like webphp, only localhost should be needed. Anything that is use facing should be as limited as possible in both scope and authority. You want a connection to fail if localhost somehow is no longer valid.